# How to log line breaks in default Magento log?

Tags: magento-1.9, log

This might be a too simple question for someone. How can I get a line break in my .log file by using `Mage::log()`? Whatever I pass to log() it treats as a string. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass a Linux line break with double quotes

```
"\n"
```

Or if you are dumping an array, use a print method

```
print_r($array, true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. And +1 for the quick response.

Comment: I tried `\n` but it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of "\n" you can just use

`PHP_EOL`

So you could type something like:

`Mage::log(PHP_EOL.$your_message);`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!